# Open/link new activity after Click on "GoogleSignInButton" in Android Studio (Connected with Firebase)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I want to link to new interface/activity after i click on Google Sign-In Button in Android Studio. I am using Firebase database.

After login in MainLogin interface, I would like to jump to another interface called MainActivity. Could anyone pls tell me how to do it. Thanks alot..

### MainLogin.java

```
package com.example.xh3al3r.myapplication2;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider;

public class MainLogin extends AppCompatActivity {
SignInButton signIn;
int RC_SIGN_IN=1;
GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
String TAG="MainLogin";
FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_login);
// Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and basic
// profile. ID and basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.
        signIn=(SignInButton)findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
        mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        // Configure Google Sign In
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();


        // Build a GoogleSignInClient with the options specified by gso.
        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
        signIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                signIn();
            }
        });
    }

    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            try {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            } catch (ApiException e) {
                // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
                Log.w(TAG, "Google sign in failed", e);
                // ...
            }
        }


    }
    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
        Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());

        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            updateUI(user);
                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(MainLogin.this,"You are Not Able to Login to Google",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            updateUI(null);
                        }

                        // ...
                    }
                });
    }
private void updateUI(FirebaseUser user) {
    GoogleSignInAccount acct = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(getApplicationContext());
    if (acct != null) {
        String personName = acct.getDisplayName();
        String personGivenName = acct.getGivenName();
        String personFamilyName = acct.getFamilyName();
        String personEmail = acct.getEmail();
        String personId = acct.getId();
        Uri personPhoto = acct.getPhotoUrl();
        Toast.makeText(this,"Name :"+ personName+ "User id :"+ personId,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

}
```

Conclusion:
1.Sign in via GoogleSigninButton integrated with Firebase in Android Studio
2. Successful should link to MainActivity.xml 
--The login button can function very well, just wonder how to link to my specific xml activity.--***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void openActivity(){
    Intent i=new Intent(MainLogin.this,MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}

 private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
    Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());

    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        updateUI(user);

                        //now open the new activity and end the current activity
                        openActivity();
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(MainLogin.this,"You are Not Able to Login to Google",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        updateUI(null);
                    }

                    // ...
                }
            });
          }
```

Comment: should i replace public void OnCreate method?

Comment: @JesscyTey no need to replace OnCreate() just add the openActivity() method.

Comment: So everything remain the same, just add the new openActivity() method right? @abdul rehman

Comment: but it was clashing with  private void signIn() method

Comment: @JesscyTey add new Method and use it in firebaseAuthWithGoogle() , inside onComplete().

Comment: and please mark the answer as correct. Thankyou @JesscyTey

Comment: how it is clashing with signIn(). can you share the code.

Comment: @JesscyTey no problem just click on the up arrow on left side of answer.

Comment: To accept an answer:

-Choose one answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem.
-To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.
-You may change which answer is accepted, or simply un-accept the answer, at any time.